# Formateo de un texto en listas y diccionarios.-

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

quiero formatear en una lista y dentro de ésta, un diccionario de una cadena. Sin ser una cadena, tengo lo siguiente:

```
listas = [{"idSorteo":"1225806004","idJuego":"06","categoria":1,"repartidoEn":[{"nombreComercial":"EDUARDO LOSILLA","direccion":"GRAN VIA CORTS CATALANES 492","poblacion":"BARCELONA","provincia":"BARCELONA","codigoPostal":"08015","telefono":"934546004","idReceptor":10825,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/barcelona/eduardo-losilla"},{"nombreComercial":"LA PASTORETA","direccion":"PZA. DE LA PASTORETA, 6","poblacion":"REUS","provincia":"TARRAGONA","codigoPostal":"43205","telefono":"977323317","idReceptor":75930,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/tarragona/la-pastoreta"}]},{"idSorteo":"1225806004","idJuego":"06","categoria":2,"repartidoEn":[{"nombreComercial":"-","direccion":"PORTA PINTADA, 3","poblacion":"PALMA DE MALLORCA","provincia":"BALEARES","codigoPostal":"07002","telefono":"971726058","idReceptor":61525,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/baleares/3057"},{"nombreComercial":"EDUARDO LOSILLA","direccion":"GRAN VIA CORTS CATALANES 492","poblacion":"BARCELONA","provincia":"BARCELONA","codigoPostal":"08015","telefono":"934546004","idReceptor":10825,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/barcelona/eduardo-losilla"},{"nombreComercial":"-","direccion":"DOCTOR ESQUERDO, 118","poblacion":"MADRID","provincia":"MADRID","codigoPostal":"28007","telefono":"915529961","idReceptor":95350,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/madrid/12623"},{"nombreComercial":"-","direccion":"MAJANO, 17","poblacion":"GUAMASA","provincia":"STA.CRUZ.TFE","codigoPostal":"38330","telefono":"922577345","idReceptor":68155,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/sta-cruz-tfe/386106"},{"nombreComercial":"LA PASTORETA","direccion":"PZA. DE LA PASTORETA, 6","poblacion":"REUS","provincia":"TARRAGONA","codigoPostal":"43205","telefono":"977323317","idReceptor":75930,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/tarragona/la-pastoreta"}]}]

print (type(listas),'-----')
for lista in listas:
    print ('categoria',lista['categoria'])
    for repartos in lista['repartidoEn']:
        print (repartos['direccion'])
```

Resultado (deseado):

<class 'list'> -----

categoria 1

GRAN VIA CORTS CATALANES 492

PZA. DE LA PASTORETA, 6

categoria 2
PORTA PINTADA, 3

GRAN VIA CORTS CATALANES 492

DOCTOR ESQUERDO, 118

MAJANO, 17

PZA. DE LA PASTORETA, 6

Pero la variable "listas" me viene en cadena. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#"}', '"id
#"}]},{"id

listas = listas.replace('"}]},{"id','"}]}**{"id')
ll = listas.split('**')
lis = list()
for l in ll:
    x =l.replace('","idJuego":"','"**"idJuego":"').replace('","categoria"','"**"categoria"').replace(',"repartidoEn"','**"repartidoEn"').split('**')
    lis.append(x)

for y in lis:
    print (type(y),y)
    print ('=========')
```

... y es hasta aquí donde he llegado, quisiera recuperar la información, como si no fuera un string. He probado con ast y con json, pero me marca errores de que no tiene formato de diccionario.
Agradecería una ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hace falta ni json, ni ast, ni ninguna librería. Python tiene la función integrada eval que es capaz de transformar un string en una expresión. Su uso es como el siguiente:

```
x="Hola mundo!"
print(eval("x")) # Devuelve "Hola mundo!"
```

Visto esto, si tu lista en vez de ser tipo "list" es de tipo "str", podrías aplicar eval de la siguiente manera:

```
lista = eval(lista)
```

El código final quedaría así:

```
listas = '[{"idSorteo":"1225806004","idJuego":"06","categoria":1,"repartidoEn":[{"nombreComercial":"EDUARDO LOSILLA","direccion":"GRAN VIA CORTS CATALANES 492","poblacion":"BARCELONA","provincia":"BARCELONA","codigoPostal":"08015","telefono":"934546004","idReceptor":10825,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/barcelona/eduardo-losilla"},{"nombreComercial":"LA PASTORETA","direccion":"PZA. DE LA PASTORETA, 6","poblacion":"REUS","provincia":"TARRAGONA","codigoPostal":"43205","telefono":"977323317","idReceptor":75930,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/tarragona/la-pastoreta"}]},{"idSorteo":"1225806004","idJuego":"06","categoria":2,"repartidoEn":[{"nombreComercial":"-","direccion":"PORTA PINTADA, 3","poblacion":"PALMA DE MALLORCA","provincia":"BALEARES","codigoPostal":"07002","telefono":"971726058","idReceptor":61525,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/baleares/3057"},{"nombreComercial":"EDUARDO LOSILLA","direccion":"GRAN VIA CORTS CATALANES 492","poblacion":"BARCELONA","provincia":"BARCELONA","codigoPostal":"08015","telefono":"934546004","idReceptor":10825,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/barcelona/eduardo-losilla"},{"nombreComercial":"-","direccion":"DOCTOR ESQUERDO, 118","poblacion":"MADRID","provincia":"MADRID","codigoPostal":"28007","telefono":"915529961","idReceptor":95350,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/madrid/12623"},{"nombreComercial":"-","direccion":"MAJANO, 17","poblacion":"GUAMASA","provincia":"STA.CRUZ.TFE","codigoPostal":"38330","telefono":"922577345","idReceptor":68155,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/sta-cruz-tfe/386106"},{"nombreComercial":"LA PASTORETA","direccion":"PZA. DE LA PASTORETA, 6","poblacion":"REUS","provincia":"TARRAGONA","codigoPostal":"43205","telefono":"977323317","idReceptor":75930,"isOnlineSale":False,"furl":"/red-comercial/tarragona/la-pastoreta"}]}]'
listas = eval(listas)

print (type(listas),'-----')
for lista in listas:
    print ('categoria',lista['categoria'])
    for repartos in lista['repartidoEn']:
        print (repartos['direccion'])
```

Aquí te dejo un [enlace](https://pythongeeks.org/python-eval-function/) por si estás interesado en la función eval y sus aplicaciones

Comment: **importante** El uso de eval, exec y otras formas de ejecutar código Python sin restricciones debe evitarse para parsear datos no confiables. Esto debido a que podría escribirse código malicioso en lugar del dato esperado: Ejemplo `eval("__import__('os').remove('c:/windows/system32')")`. En este caso particular, `ast.literal_eval` es la mejor opción.

Comment: Gracias Daniel, después de algunas pruebas me funciona exactamente. Tenia que haberlo consultado antes, porque he dedicado algunas horas. Gracias.